# How do I log a message in color to the Xcode 15 console?

Tags: ios, xcode, logging, xcode15

Xcode 15 now displays log message in colors. For example, warnings seem to appear in yellow, while standard messages are in white.

I noticed that [Swift Log](https://github.com/apple/swift-log) ([tutorial](https://nshipster.com/swift-log/)) has a color scheme as well:

[image]

Do I need to include Swift Log in my iOS app to output messages in color, or is there a built-in method to do so?

Answer (score 6):

You can [use `os.Logger` to output different severity levels](https://swiftwithmajid.com/2022/04/06/logging-in-swift/). No need to import a special library.

Note that unlike in the screenshot, Xcode only outputs 3 different colors:

```
logger.log("Log")
logger.trace("Trace")
logger.debug("Debug")
logger.info("Info")
logger.notice("Notice")
logger.warning("Warning")
logger.error("Error")
logger.critical("Critical")
logger.fault("Fault")
```

Example output in the Xcode Console:

[image]